# trace of the matrix $I + M + M^2$ is

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $ \alpha = e^{\frac{2\pi \iota}{5}}$  and the matrix 
>   $$ M= \begin{pmatrix}1 & \alpha & \alpha^2 & \alpha^3 & \alpha^4\\ 
> 0 & \alpha & \alpha^2 & \alpha^3 & \alpha^4\\
> 0 & 0 & \alpha^2 & \alpha^3 & \alpha^4 \\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & \alpha^3 & \alpha^4\\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \alpha^4 \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> Then the trace of the  matrix $I + M + M^2$ is
>
> 1. $-5$;
> 2. $0$;
> 3. $3$;
> 4. $5$.

I am stuck on this problem. Can anyone help me please?

I got trace of the matrix $$\operatorname{tr}(I+M+M^2) = 7 + \alpha + 2  \alpha^2   + \alpha^3 + 2 \alpha^4 + \alpha^6 +\alpha^8.$$ Now what to do?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are matrices, what do you know about $tr(AB)$?

Comment: It will be good if you give what you tried and where exactly you got struck.

Comment: I wonder why this question was so heavily down-voted.

Comment: @Prasanta Can you explain what happens to the elements on the diagonal when you multiply 2 upper triangular matrices? For example, can you tell me what are the elements on the diagonal of $M^2$ without actually doing the multiplication?

Comment: @Prasanta Use that fact that since $\alpha = 2^{ \frac {2\pi i}{5}}$ is a fifth root of unity, so $\alpha^5 = 1, 1 + \alpha + \alpha^2 + \alpha^3 + \alpha^4 = 0$

Comment: @Prasantha, Calvin Lin gave you enough hints, see them

Comment: I got it , its answer is 5.........thanks to all.....

Comment: @Prasanta Why don't you write up your solution and post it, so others can read it?

Comment: $$tr(I+M+M^2) = 7 + \alpha + 2  \alpha^2   + \alpha^3 + 2 \alpha^4 + \alpha^6 +\alpha^8 $$  now using $$\alpha^5 =1,1+\alpha+\alpha^2+\alpha^3+\alpha^4=0 $$  its 5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that the trace of $M$ is $0$, since $1+\alpha+\alpha^2+\alpha^3+\alpha^4= 0$.

Also $M$ is upper triangular so that $M^2$ has diagonal elements which are just the square of the diagonal elements of $M$, i.e. $1,\alpha^2, \alpha^4, \alpha^6, \alpha^8$.

Using the fact that $\alpha^5 = 1$ we see that the trace of $M^2$ is again $0$.

Thus tr$(I+M+M^2)$ = tr$(I)$ = 5.