# The maximum value of the function $f (x, y, z) = xyz$

Tags: real-analysis

> The maximum value of the function $$f (x, y, z) = xyz $$subject to the constraint
>   $$xy+yz+zx-a =0, a >0$$ is
>
> 1. $a^{3/2}$
> 2. $\left(\dfrac{a}{3} \right) ^{3/2}$
> 3. $\left(\dfrac{3}{a} \right) ^{3/2}$
> 4. $\left(\dfrac{3a}{2} \right) ^{3/2}$

I am stuck on this problem. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What do you know to solve this problem? Do you know classical inequalities? Calculus? Lagrangian? What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: @  Calvin Lin sir, I don't know where to begin.........

Comment: @Prasanta Are $x,y,z$ given to be positive?

Comment: As you don't know where to start, I am giving you hint.
Like in any other Optimization problems of such type, start with derivatives

Comment: @  Marvis sir, sign of $x,y,z$ is not given in the question.......

Comment: @Prasanta If $(x,y,z)$ are allowed to be negative, then the maximum is $\infty$, since $(x,y,z) = \left(-n,-n, \dfrac{n}2 - \dfrac{a}{2n} \right)$, which satisfies $xy+yz+zx = a$ and we get $xyz = \dfrac{n^3}2 - \dfrac{an}2$. Now let $n \to \infty$, to get the maximum as $\infty$.

Comment: I don't get why these questions by Prasanta are getting down voted. You may think that they are silly/easy, but OP doesn't know how to approach them AND is willing to work through these with some guidance. For that, he deserves to be up voted. Take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268029/trace-of-the-matrix-i-m-m2-is for example.

Comment: @Marvis: Dear Marvis I know that if we consider $F(x,y,z)=0$ subject to constraint condition $G(x,y,z)=0$ then the necessary condition that $F$ have an extreme is $F_xG_y-F_yG_x=0$. As I did this didn't hold for this problem. It seems strange to me or I am missing something? Thanks.

Comment: @BabakSorouh How do you get the condition $F_x G_y - F_y G_x = 0$?

Comment: @Marvis: It is a solved problem in  Advanced Calculus by M.R.Spiegel. He proved that there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**  I'll assume that $x,y,z>0$, since otherwise as Marvis points out, the maximum would be infinite.  Applying the AM-GM inequality.  We find that $$\left(\frac{xy+yz+zx}{3}\right)^3\geq (xyz)^2=f(x,y,z)^2.$$

Also, what happens when we set $$x=y=z=\left(\frac{a}{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$  Use this to complete the problem.

Comment: Provided $x,y,z > 0$

Comment: Your first statement is incorrect. See my comment to the question, where it is shown that if $(x,y,z)$ are allowed to be negative, then the maximum is in fact $\infty$.

Comment: @Marvis: Ahh, yes, thank you.  I corrected my posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

By arithmetic-geometic inequality, 
$$\frac{xy+xz+yz}3\ge \sqrt[3]{xy\cdot xz\cdot yz}$$
provided $xy,xz,yz$ are all positive (i.e. $x,y,z$ have the same sign, e.g. are all positive) and with equality iff $xy=yz=xz$ (i.e. iff $x=y=z$).
The left hand side is $\frac a3$ and the right hand side is $f(x,y,z)^{\frac23}$.

However, if $x,y,zh$ are allowed to have differnt signs, there is no absolute maximum: If $t>0$ and $y=z=-t$, then $x=t-\frac a{2t}$ produces $f(x,y,z)=t^3-\frac12at$, which becomes arbitrarily large.